# multiple installs of (nearly) the same app

Tags: android, package, installation, apk

I made an app (com.example) using Android Studio 2.2.
This app displays a logo (PNG image) on the main activity.
Now i want to make a new package of the same app in order to install both on my device. there are two differences:
the logo and the label.
i tried to change the package name in manifest, from:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example">
```

to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newLogo">
```

sadly it break all

```
import static com.example.R.string.MyGreateString;
```

references. is there a smart way to avoid the rename of all imports or to rename a package?

Comment: Use Android Studio's refactor ability to rename the root package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a gradle flavor for each build type in each app (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) for an explanation) and define an applicationId for each flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    A {
         applicationId "com.example.newLogo"
    }
    B {
         applicationId "com.example"
    }
}
```

Comment: good one! how can i get current buldVariant in code (to use different logos)? how can i use different app_name (res/strings) to change displayed name?

Comment: You can do a lot of stuff like that with flavors. You can have dedicates assets per flavor and any other resource - read the docs to see all the options (and there are many) - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Answer (score 0):

go to File>Project Structure> app>Flavors tab and change or add (+) the Application Id

[image: AndroidStudio]